# Objective c - insert character into string between certain characters

Tags: objective-c, string, insert

I need to insert a character into a string between each occurrence of strings that I have in an array. For example:

```
array = [ab,bc,cd,de];
string = @"abbccd";

newString = @"ab*bc*cd";
```

How can I accomplish this? I looked around but couldn't find a good solution. Thanks.

Comment: What if the string contains substrings that aren't in the array?

Answer (score 2):

How about,

```
NSString *newString = [array componentsJoinedByString:@"*"];
```